# How can I import "@tensorflow/tfjs" module in javascript.?

Tags: tensorflow.js

I've been trying to import "@tensorflow/tfjs" for the last few hours. I have used both methods (import or require),but errors are occurs both times.
When I use use import statement then:-
Error is:Cannot use import statement outside a module.
And when I use require statement then:-
Error is=ReferenceError:require is not defined.
Javascript files and tensorflow.tfjs file both are in same folder(In vs code).

I am trying to use tensorflow.js in javascript program to learn AI technology.